# Save data to file when click on submit button

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I have written a CGI-Perl Script which runs the remote command on the storage box and keep the output on the array.I want to save that array data to File in the server which user click on the submit button and redirect to next page.

How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: No code, no effort. Cross post at Perlmonks: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1104749

Comment: Sorry  for the no incomplete info in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Start by naming the files based on the date. Dates are great for file names. Maybe add a .txt extension. Open a filehandle for that name. Print to the filehandle.

The following is a rough approximation of what it would look like. The syntax might be a little off:

```
my $filename = time() . ".txt";   #something like 234242342352.txt
open my $fh, ">", $filename or die "Could not write to $filename"; 
print $fh @array_data;  #this assumes your array still has newline characters
```

I'm not sure how going to the next page works.